# Joomla getUser() does not show the updated user data

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Below code allows me to show the user's name in the profile page of the Joomla profile of a user. Given that I have overridden the template to get the look and feel I want.

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();

if (!$user->guest) {
  echo 'You are logged in as:<br />';
  echo 'Real name: ' . $user->name . '';
}
```

My problem is I allow user to update his or her profile. After he updates the his name, database is updated correctly but it does not show the updated name in the profile page.

When I go through Joomla docs I found out that user data is stored in the session(JFactory::getUser()). If I `print_r($_SESSION)` I can see the user data object. Also If I log out then log in again updated name is shown on the profile page.

How can I show the update details in the profile page once the data has been updated? Is there a way to update the session data in the Joomla session rather than manually doing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should use JSession to set new data for your user's current session

```
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $session->set('user', new JUser($user->id));
        //new data for your user after the update
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        print_r($user);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know in the latest Joomla 2.5.9 this is still an issue, and the temporary solution is something like this added to the components/com_users/controllers/profile.php edit function AFTER successfully saving the user record.

```
// Get session user object
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$tmpUser = $session->get('user');

// Update necessary fields
$tmpUser->name  = $data['name'];
$tmpUser->email = $data['email1'];

// Update the session user object
$session->set('user', $tmpUser);
```

You CANNOT simply use the previously recommended set('user', new JUser($user->id)); solution because you are not storing all of the data found in the Joomla session user object (access permissions).

Answer (score 0):

It's actually harder than it looks and essentially you need to make them reauthenicate. It is because of the messy way that JUser and JSession interact.

Comment: Oh if you just want to do it for yourself i.e. change your own name sure. That won't change another user's session though.