# How do i force Joomla to update the user session

Tags: php, joomla, acl

I'm updating the ACL for a given user on a PayPal callback. I'm doing this by updating the #__user_usergroup_map table directly. Now i need the user session to be updated with the new information without logging out and in again.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028816/joomla-getuser-does-not-show-the-updated-user-data)'s answers i tried the following:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('user', new JUser($user->id));
```

However this does not work for me and from [JUser](http://docs.joomla.org/API17:JUser) it looks like JUser has been deprecated.

Can anyone hint me in the right direction?

Comment: which information exactly are you trying to update within the session?

Comment: @Lodder I'm adding an extra user group to the user.

Answer (score 4):

I realized that the answer from the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028816/joomla-getuser-does-not-show-the-updated-user-data) will actually work.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('user', new JUser($user->id));
```

The reason it wouldn't update the user session in my case is that this code was called on the callback from PayPal which do not hold the user session.

Comment: This feature should be integrated in some subscription components out there as it's very handy. Thank for sharing. Don't forget to commit to the [Joomla Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla?referrer=Ph_HGDW6OiEqU7r0cS-muA2) for Stackexchange ;)

Comment: This seems to work for me. The session has the new group in it. However what it doesn't seem to do is refresh the Main Menu. The items that the new group access gives you don't appear until you log out and log back in, or run that code above a second time.